# Typescript express not working after switching to esnext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, typeorm

I'm working on a react typescript application. Because of 'top level await' issues, I want to change my target and module to 'es2017' and 'esnext' respectively.
Changing the target to 'es2017' works fine, but the moment I change the module to 'esnext' my app crashes on startup.

The problem is an express route that no longer works:

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

Here's the specific code in my server.ts

```
const {all_users} = require("./controllers/UserController");
express.get("/users", all_users);
```

UserController.ts:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "../entities/User";


exports.all_users = function(req, res) {
    createConnection().then(async connection => {
        const users = await connection.manager.find(User);        
        res.json({users});
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,      
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "resolveJsonModule": true      
    },   
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"         
    ]
}
```

Is this a known problem with esnext?

Comment: `all_users` is `undefined`. What does it show if you log it in the console? How bout if you import *?

Comment: when I log it, it is indeed undefined.
However, when I set my `tsconfig.json` `'module'='commonjs'` ,it runs without error and shows `all_users` as `'function (anonymous)'`

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the declaration of `all_users` to:

```
export function all_users(req, res) {
```